# Using the First Isomorphism to show $R[x]/((x-a)^2)$ is isomorphic to $R[x]/(x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can I use the First Isomorphism to show $R[x]/((x-a)^2)$ is isomorphic to $R[x]/(x^2)$. I tried to find an isomorphism $\phi : R[x] \rightarrow R[x]/(x^2)$ and define this by $\phi (f) = f(a)$ but then I don't know how to show this is surjective as I don't understand what elements in $R[x]/(x^2)$ actually look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take$$\begin{array}{rccc}\phi\colon&\mathbb R[x]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)\\&p(x)&\mapsto&p(x+a)+(x^2).\end{array}$$Then, yes, $\ker\phi=\bigl((x-a)^2\bigr)$. And this map $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please help me understand what the element of $R[x]/(x)^2$ actually look like so I can make a convincing argument for surjectivity?

Comment: An element of $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ is of the form $p(x)+(x^2)$ for some polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb R[x]$. So, $\phi$ is surjective since, if $q(x)=p(x-a)$, then $\phi\bigl(q(x)\bigr)=p(x)+(x^2)$.

Comment: Is 0 in the quotient ring $R[x]/(x^2)$ actually the element $(x^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f\mapsto f(a)$ is not a map into $R[x]/((x-a)^2)$. It's a map into $R$. It's also not true that its kernel is $((x-a)^2)$. Its kernel is $(x-a)$.

Instead, define $\phi(f)(x)=f(x-a)$ which is a map $R[x]\to R[x]$ which is clearly an isomorphism (with inverse $f(x)\mapsto f(x+a)$.) Thus, composing with the quotient map yields a surjective ring homomorphism $\overline{\phi}:R[x]\to R[x]/((x-a)^2)$. Hence, $R[x]/((x-a)^2)\cong R[x]/\textrm{ker}(\phi)$.

However, it's clear that $\textrm{ker}(\phi)=(x^2)$, since $(x-a)^2| f(x-a)$ if and only if $x^2|f(x)$.

Comment: Is it possible to reverse this argument so that the composed homomorphism goes from $R[x] \rightarrow R[x]/(x^2)$ instead, and $ker \phi = (x-a)^2$

Comment: Also I dont understand the final line as haven't you shown $R[x]/(x-a)^2$ is isomorphic to itself?

Comment: Of course, this argument admits reversal with $\phi$ replaced $\phi^{-1}$ and drawing the same conclusion.

Comment: And in the final line, that was a typo (as it was written, the rest of the sentence also didn't make sense).

Comment: Basically if $f=qg$ for polynomials $f,g,q$, then $f(x-a)=q(x-a)g(x-a)$. This argument is clearly reversible, so you get and if and only if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The map $x\mapsto x+a$ (together with the canonical embedding $R\to R[x]$) induces a homomorphism $R[x]\to R[x]$. As this leads to $x-a\mapsto x$, it is clearly onto (in fact, it is an automorphism with the inverse being induced by $x\mapsto x-a$).
 Compose with the canonical projection $R[x]\to R[x]/(x^2)$ to obtain a homomorphism $\phi\colon R[x]\to R[x]/(x^2)$. Wie have $f(x)\in\ker\phi$ iff $f(x+a)$ is a multiple of $x^2$. The latter is clearly equivalent to $f(x)$ being a multiple of $(x-a)^2$. Thus $\ker\phi=((x-a)^2)$ and by the isomorphism theorem $\phi$ induces an isomorphism $R[x]/((x-a)^2)\to R[x]/(x^2)$.

$$\begin{matrix}
0\to &((x-a)^2)&\to& R[x]&\longrightarrow &R[x]/((x-a)^2)&\to0\\
&&&\downarrow\rlap{{x\mapsto x+a}}&&\downarrow\rlap{\cong}\\
0\to &(x^2)&\to& R[x]&\longrightarrow &R[x]/(x^2)&\to0\\
 \end{matrix}$$